# Check if mouse is over multiple elements in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, element

So I'm working on a drop down menu and ran into an issue...here is the code...

```
$('#layer2_cell1').hide();

$("#layer1_cell1").mouseenter(function () {
    $('#layer2_cell1').show();
    $("#storage").data('airplanesmain', '1');
});
$("#layer1_cell1").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#storage").data('airplanesmain', '0');
    var subcell = $("#storage").data('airplanessubcell');
    if (subcell == '0') {
        $('#layer2_cell1').hide();
    }
});
$("#layer2_cell1").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#storage").data('airplanessubcell', '1');
});
$("#layer2_cell1").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#storage").data('airplanessubcell', '0');
});
```

I'm trying to hide layer2_cell1 if my mouse is outside of the layer1_cell1 and layer2_cell1 this seems like it would do it but it dosnt. Help!

Comment: could you post the minimum html, css and js needed in a jsfiddle - it helps a lot. Also, have you considered a pure CSS dropdown, theres no reason to use js for just showing and hiding...

Comment: Js fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/Q4f2N/2/ It dosnt work there but just take all the code and upload it into this file system...category_application folder inside there there is category_application.html which is where html code goes...there is also a folder called java a folder called css. Dont worry about the images. inside java folder there is Jquery.js and menu.js, menu.js contains java code. then inside css there is sheet.css which contains css.

Comment: You put your css in the javascript box and vise versa. checking it out now updated --> http://jsfiddle.net/Q4f2N/3/

Comment: Your code is so far beyond standards, I suggest scratching what you have and starting again with a good tutorial on CSS dropdowns, as @Chimoo suggested. Never before have I ever seen anyone use JQUERY to insert a FONT tag into a TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have written a CSS only menu here http://jsfiddle.net/P8ZH6/3/ as there is no need to use JavaScript.

You can attach JavaScript events to the menu items if you need them to display the dynamic content above the menu.

Something like this could work.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".menu li").hover(function(){
   $("#dynamic_content").html($(this).parents(".menu_1").find("span").html() + "->" + $(this).find("a").text());
})

$(".menu .menu_1 span").hover(function(){
   $("#dynamic_content").html($(this).html());
})

$(".menu li, .menu .menu_1 span").mouseout(function(){
   $("#dynamic_content").html("");
 });
```

});
​

Hope this works for you.